# Importing new layout to existing ArcMap file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, layouts, arcgis-10.7

I am a new user of ArcMap and started with setting up data and I am now happy with the symbology styling I have set up. My data includes a mix of inhouse geodatabases, WMS feeds and shapefiles I create for specific one-off projects.

When I was being set up, another user set up a map layout which is not adequate for my purposes.  I have now located standard layout formats that I want to replace my current one with. Ideally I want to keep the general symbology styling the same, and change the layout to suit an individual project.

Is it possible to either replace/create a new map layout after one has already been started, or copy my data symbology into a new map based on the standard layouts?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so.

The way that I would try to do this is by using the Change Layout button on the Layout toolbar.

That button is mentioned in [A quick tour of page layouts](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/a-quick-tour-of-page-layouts.htm) where it says that you:

> Use the Change Layout button Change Layout on the Layout toolbar to
>   change page orientation and element placement of an existing layout.

It is also mentioned in the help about [Using map templates](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/using-mxd-templates.htm).